# Django Name Groups Urls.py

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a url mapping for a User Account email activation system. After registration, the user is sent an email with a url to follow. The link is in the form of **domain**/login/activate/**confirmation_code**/Username. I'm trying to figure out out to use named groups in the Django url dispatcher so I can pass confirmation_code and username as arguments to the def in my view. However, I can't seem to figure it out. Thank you for any help.
I have been referencing: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/

my urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from login import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
     url(r'^register/$', views.registration, name='index.html'),
     url(r'^authenticate/$', views.authenticateLogin, name='index.html'),
     url(r'^authenticateUser/$', views.authenticateUser, name='index.html'),
     url(r'^activate/(?P<confirmation_code>\d{4}/?P<username>\d{4})/$', views.activate)
)
```

error message:

```
Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^admin/
^blogadmin/
^ ^$ [name='index']
^ ^about/$ [name='about']
^ ^contact/$ [name='contact']
^ ^$ [name='index']
^login/ ^register/$ [name='index.html']
^login/ ^authenticate/$ [name='index.html']
^login/ ^authenticateUser/$ [name='index.html']
^login/ ^activate/(?P<confirmation_code>\d{4})/(?P<username>\d{4})/$ [name='activate']
^blog/
^webstore/
^companion/
The current URL, login/activate/o5y0WONgVpyXELEIuNg9xp3lCVod35JDB/pdf2e, didn't match any   of these.
```

Thanks karthikr and Jingo for your Answers

Resolution:

```
url(r'^activate/(?P<confirmation_code>[\w]+)/(?P<username>[\w]+/)$', views.activate, {}, 'activate')
```

Comment: when you say `\d{4}` it is matching only 4 digits. Change that to `[\w]+` to match `o5y0WONgVpyXELEIuNg9xp3lCVod35JDB `

Comment: This worked. I also had to use Jingo's answer too. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set the brackets for the named groups wrong, try like this:

```
url(r'^activate/(?P<confirmation_code>[\w]{1,33})/(?P<username>\[\w]+)/$', 'views.activate', {}, 'activate')
```

HTH :)

Update: 
Try like above if your token is up to 33 characters (alpha-numeric).

Comment: Thanks for the response! Unfortunately, still a no go. Getting a 404. I added the error message.